# Add product customizable option to product cart programatically Magento 2

Tags: product, magento-2.1, cart

I created a custom option in backend like this:

[image]

I have a custom extension to call a controller which will add the product to cart programmatically like this:

```
public function __construct(
      Context $context,
      \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
      \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart, \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
      \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ){
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_cart = $cart;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->observer = $observer;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $observer = $this->observer; 
        $option = '95';
        $productId = '14';
        $qty = '1'; 

        $params = array(
            'product' => $productId,
            'qty' => $qty
        );
        $_product = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
        $customOptions[] = $option;
        $_product->setOptions($customOptions);
        $this->_cart->addProduct($_product,$params); 
        $this->_cart->save();
    }
```

But I got an error like this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function groupFactory() on string in /var/www/project/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Type/AbstractType.php:580
```

the option for this product is defined like this:

```
Array
(
    [option_id] => 18
    [product_id] => 14
    [type] => drop_down
    [is_require] => 1
    [sku] => 
    [max_characters] => 0
    [file_extension] => 
    [image_size_x] => 0
    [image_size_y] => 0
    [sort_order] => 1
    [default_title] => Phone Model
    [store_title] => 
    [title] => Phone Model
    [default_price] => 
    [default_price_type] => 
    [store_price] => 
    [store_price_type] => 
    [price] => 
    [price_type] => 
)
```

i got the above array result by using this code:

```
$customOptions = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($_product);
        foreach ($customOptions as $customOption) {
          echo "<pre>";
          print_r($customOption->getData());
        }
        exit;
```

the value for this option is defined in variable **$option**

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @ShellSuite Have you get solution. I am facing same issue.